# iOS : NSJSONSerialization: Wrong code or wrong JSON structure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsjsonserialization

I have some trouble with parsing my JSON object for the past 6 hours. In my code, I stripped a JSON response from server (which has been saved as a NSData object) using the following method:

```
NSMutableDictionary * responseDataRaw = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:serverResponse options: kNilOptions error:nil];
```

And this is the NSMutableDictionary structure I'm able to NSlog:

```
{
Content =     (
            {
        0 =             (
                            {
                DatePosted = "September 23, 2014 at 09:10pm";
                ID = 64;
                MemberID = "Ken Ang";
                Message = "I won't be left out :D";
                PostNumber = 1;
                Status = 1;
                Subject = "Hello from US!";
                TopicID =                     {
                    DatePosted = "September 23, 2014";
                    Enabled = "<span class='label' style='background-color:#17A647; color:#fff'>Yes</span>";
                    ForumID = 1;
                    FriendlyURL = "19-";
                    ID = 19;
                    MemberID = 1;
                    Title = "Hello from US!";
                    ViewCount = 288;
                };
                UserID = 1;
                Username = kenang;
            }
        );
        1 =             (
                            {
                DatePosted = "December 17, 2014 at 03:27pm";
                ID = 66;
                MemberID = "Nobody know";
                Message = "Hai from Chech";
                PostNumber = 2;
                Status = 1;
                Subject = "Re: Hello from US!";
                TopicID =                     {
                    DatePosted = "September 23, 2014";
                    Enabled = "<span class='label' style='background-color:#17A647; color:#fff'>Yes</span>";
                    ForumID = 1;
                    FriendlyURL = "19-";
                    ID = 19;
                    MemberID = 1;
                    Title = "Hello from US!";
                    ViewCount = 288;
                };
                UserID = 15;
                Username = admin;
            }
        );
        Forum = "Member Introduction";
        ForumID = 1;
        ForumTopicTitle = "Hello from US!";
    }
);
Count = 2;
}
```

Then I intend to save the value of "0" and "1" as NSDictionary using the following method but was prompted an error at runtime:

```
NSArray * responseData = [responseDataRaw objectForKey:@"Content"];

for (id arrayItems in responseData)
{
    NSMutableArray * validKeys = [NSMutableArray array];

    //Enumerate and collect the valid keys: only "0" and "1". So will do a numeric test.
    for (id itemsInside in [arrayItems allKeys])
    {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:itemsInside];
        BOOL isNumeric = [scanner scanInteger:NULL] && [scanner isAtEnd];

        if (isNumeric)
        {
            [validKeys addObject:itemsInside];

        }

}


//Using the key to parse the info into our readable NSDictionary
for (NSString * individualKey in validKeys)
{
    NSDictionary * testPost = [arrayItems objectForKey:individualKey];
    ....
    ....
}
```

I can't save the value as a NSDictionary at the variable testPost. The error message I've got is

```
[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170465040
```

Anyone has any idea what should I do? I need to save the "0" and "1" values as dictionary as I would need items in them to pluck into a table cell later.

Help!!

Comment: use this site to validade your json http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira I've validated and its a valid JSON.

Comment: If it wasn't correct json, it wouldn't has successfully parsed to a dictionary @ErasmoOliveira

Comment: That's the strange part. I've validated it at jsonlint.com and its alright. And I've worked more than 6 hours trying solve it . The furthest part I've went is where Xcode tells me the value of "0" and "1" is not a valid NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira The above is already the NSMutableDictionary serialized by the NSJSONSerialization method. The original JSON string pre-serialized comes with exactly "Content:" as you mentioned.

Comment: Have you got two instances of validKeys? The one defined in the first for loop can't be accessed from the second for loop.

Comment: The error message tells you clearly that you sent `objectForKey` to an `NSArray` instance, but your code is treating it as an `NSDictionary` - look at which line this occurs on and then examine the object in the debugger - you will see where you have made an incorrect assumption

Comment: As @AirsourceLtd said there are some weird things in your code, I'm not even sure it compiles (in particular, the scopes of `validKeys` and `arrayItems`).

Comment: Thanks @AirsourceLtd for pointing out the mistake that may have cost me another hour to debug. I moved the validKeys out of both loops but still does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the tip. I went back to inspect my instance types and bravo, testPost is a NSArray and only the items inside its array are NSDictionaries!! I extracted out testPost as a NSArray and then loop through its items and save them as NSDictionaries. Problem solved!! If you don't mind, write your comment as an answer so I can accept them. A million thanks!

Comment: Helps to use types other than id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you clearly that you sent `objectForKey` to an `NSArray` instance, but your code is treating it as an NSDictionary - look at which line this occurs on and then examine the object in the debugger - you will see where you have made an incorrect assumption.